# Should coercivity for making electromagnets be high?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

I have been studying the Hysteresis loop for ferromagnetic materials in my textbook. Now I know that coercivity represents the amount of current to apply in opposite direction of retained magnetic field so for any magnet, coercivity should be high so as to  prevent it losing out on its magnetic field due to external causes. Please answer in Yes/No format followed by an explanation. (It is not a homework problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you want a low coercivity.

Typical application of an electromagnet is to hold a door open. You want the door to close when the current of the solenoid is switched off. So that means a low coercivity and a low remanence.

The same reasoning applies for other applications like a magnetic valve: you want the gas supply to stop when the electrical power disappears.

In other applications (doors of cupboards etc) one uses a permanent magnet.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you wish  to do with the magnetic material. If you want to use it as the core of an inductor then you wish to have $H_c$ as small as possible to reduce dissipation per AC cycle. If you want to have it as a *permanent* magnet then having as large $H_c$ as possible is a good idea because there is no need for changing the magnetic state and the larger the $H_c$ is the more difficult is to change it.

Comment: Hey Sir, Thanks for the answer but If you don't mind, Would you be kind enough to elaborate on the 'electromagnet' part of the question. Appreciate the answer!

Comment: I mean do all electromagnets aside from electromagnets require low coercivity

Comment: I really do not understand this "do all electromagnets aside from electromagnets require low coercivity".

Comment: i mean all electromagnets aside from inductors.. typo

Comment: here is a list of electromagnet applications https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet and for every one of them I think you want $H_c$ be as small as possible, i.e., having a *soft* magnetic core so that the current in the solenoid determines the flux with as little dissipation as possible per cycle. The same can be said for the read and write coil, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_storage. OTOH you want to have in the storage disk/tape high $H_c$ coercivity magnetic particles embedded so their polarization does not flip easily by noise and other unintentional influence.